# Measure distance between two ARImageAnchors in ARKit

Tags: swift, image, arkit, detection, measure

**TL;DR; Is it possible to add a SCNAction to one SCNNode attached to an ARImageAnchor that moves this node to another one attached to another ARImageAnchor?**

My undergraduate thesis involves reproducing the behavior seen in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qi3h18wJJiI). I'm using ARKit and it's not really important the iOS version or device capabilities.

What I'm trying to achieve is to join two different SCNNodes when they are close enough to do so, but it appears that their information about their position is quite irregular and seem not to correspond to their actual position in the scene.

When I print information about the two nodes I'm working on, `lldb` gives me numbers like these:

- Object X:

Anchor `.tranform.columns.3`:

```
SIMD4<Float>(0.019269282, -0.2338481, -0.2880894, 1.0)
```

Node `.worldPosition`:

```
▿ Optional<SCNVector3>
  ▿ some : SCNVector3
    - x : 0.019269282
    - y : -0.2338481
    - z : -0.2880894
```

- Object Y:

Anchor `.tranform.columns.3`:

```
SIMD4<Float>(-7.6405444, -25.205889, -26.780603, 1.0)
```

Node `.worldPosition`:

```
▿ Optional<SCNVector3>
  ▿ some : SCNVector3
    - x : -7.6405444
    - y : -25.205889
    - z : -26.780603
```

I mean, why there is much difference between the two objects' positions? (both for their anchor and node's position). Their parents are equal (the scene's root node) and are in the same scene, shouldn't they give me at least similar positions for each node?

While measuring the distance between the two objects I've noticed that the following code

```
guard let p1 = a0.atomAnchor?.transform.simd_vector3,
     let p2 = a1.atomAnchor?.transform.simd_vector3 else { return }

     let d = simd_distance(p1, p2)
     print(d)
```

would give me inconsistent measures that vary a lot depending on the camera's distance between the printed images and the phone's camera.

My ARSessionDelegate does the following:

```
extension ViewController: ARSessionDelegate {
    
    var minimumDistanceBetweenAtoms: Float {
        return 50
    }
    
    // MARK:- Delegate method
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
        guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else {
            print("anchor not found")
            return
        }

        guard let worldScene = sceneView?.scene else { print("Scene not initialized"); return }
        guard let atomFound = atoms.first(where: { $0.referenceImage.name == imageAnchor.referenceImage.name }) else {
            print("atom not found in resources")
            return
        }

        guard atomFound.type != .referenceObject else { return }
        visibleAtoms.append(atomFound)
        atomFound.initializeAtom(inScene: worldScene, withAnchor: imageAnchor)
    }
    
    
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
        guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else {
            print("anchor not found")
            return
        }
        visibleAtoms.forEach({
            guard !$0.flag else { return }
            $0.didUpdateTo(anchor: imageAnchor)
        })
    }

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
        visibleAtoms.forEach({ [weak self] a0 in
            guard !a0.isMoving(), !a0.flag else { return }
            
            self?.visibleAtoms.forEach({ a1 in
                guard !a1.isMoving(), !(a1 === a0), !a0.flag else { return }
                
                guard let p1 = a0.atomAnchor?.transform.simd_vector3,
                    let p2 = a1.atomAnchor?.transform.simd_vector3 else { return }
                
                
                let d = simd_distance(p1, p2)
                print(d)
                if d < minimumDistanceBetweenAtoms {
                    if let molecule = a0.combination(withAtom: a1) {
                        a0.flag = true
                        a1.flag = true
                    }
                }
            })
        })
    }
    
}
```

Consider the `Atom` class as an encapsulator for the node's behavior:

```
    func initializeAtom(inScene scene: SCNScene, withAnchor anchor: ARImageAnchor) {
        guard let object = type.atomObject() else { return }
        
        let (min, max) = object.boundingBox
        let size = SCNVector3Make(max.x - min.x, max.y - min.y, max.z - min.z)
        
        let widthRatio = Float(anchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.width) / size.x
        let heightRatio = Float(anchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.height) / size.z
        object.transform = SCNMatrix4(anchor.transform)
        
        guard let finalRatio = [widthRatio, heightRatio].min() else { return }
        
        let appearanceAction = SCNAction.scale(to: CGFloat(finalRatio / 2), duration: 0.4)
        appearanceAction.timingMode = .easeOut
        object.scale = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 0)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(object)
        object.runAction(appearanceAction)
        
        
        atomAnchor = anchor
        atomScene = scene
        atomObject = object
    }
    
    func didUpdateTo(anchor: ARImageAnchor) {
        guard anchor == atomAnchor else { return }
        atomAnchor = anchor
        if isMoving() { atomObject?.removeAction(forKey: "movement") }
        moveTo(newAnchor: anchor)
    }
    
    private func moveTo(newAnchor: ARAnchor, withDurationOf duration: TimeInterval = 0.3) {
        let action = SCNAction.move(to: newAnchor.transform.vector3, duration: duration)
        atomObject?.runAction(action, forKey: "movement")
    }
```

My ARWorldTrackingConfiguration just sets the reference images and runs with the arguments `[.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors]`.

I have a `Utils` file to place all usable extensions that I need, here it's the part that I use in this code:

```
extension simd_float4x4 {
    
    var vector3: SCNVector3 {
        return SCNVector3(columns.3.x, columns.3.y, columns.3.z)
    }
    
    var simd_vector3: simd_float3 {
        return simd_float3(columns.3.x, columns.3.y, columns.3.z)
    }
    
}
```

PS.: [Github code](https://github.com/guilhermePaciulli/quimicaAcessivel).